# use relational operators in switch

Tags: java, operators, switch-statement, relational

Is there a way to use relational operators (<,<=,>,>=) in a switch statement?

```
int score = 95;

switch(score)  {
   case (score >= 90):
      // do stuff
}
```

the above example (obviously) doesn't work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No you can not.**
 From [jls-14.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11)

```
The type of the Expression must be char, byte, short, int, Character, Byte, Short, Integer, String, or an enum type (§8.9), or a compile-time error occurs.
```

Relational operators (<,<=,>,>=) results in `boolean` and which is not allowded.

All of the following must be true, or a compile-time error occurs:

- Every case constant expression associated with a switch statement must be assignable (§5.2) to the type of the switch Expression.
- No two of the case constant expressions associated with a switch statement may have the same value.
- No switch label is null.
- At most one default label may be associated with the same switch statement.

Answer (score 3):

This might help you if you need to do it with switch itself,

```
char g ='X';
            int marks = 65;
            switch(marks/10)
            {
                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 4: g = 'F';
                        break;
                case 5: g = 'E';
                        break;
                case 6: g = 'D';
                        break;
                case 7: g = 'C';
                        break;
                case 8: g = 'B';
                        break;
                case 9: 
                case 10: g = 'A';       
                         break;
            }
            System.out.println(g);
```

It works this way,

```
    if(marks<50)
                g='F';
            else if(marks<60)
                g='E';
            else if(marks<70)
                g='D';
            else if(marks<80)
                g='C';
            else if(marks<90)
                g='B';
            else if(marks<=100)
                g='A';
```

Comment: This is many years old now but if you happen to see this comment, how/why does this work?

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately NO**, though you can use `case` fall (kind of hacky) by grouping multiple case statements without `break` and implement code when a range ends:

```
int score = 95;
switch(score) {
 ..
 case 79: System.out.println("value in 70-79 range"); break;
 case 80:
 ..
 case 85: System.out.println("value in 80-85 range"); break;
 case 90:
 case 91:
 case 92:
 case 93:
 case 94:
 case 95: System.out.println("value in 90-95 range"); break;
 default: break;
}
```

IMHO, using `if` would be more appropriate in your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

It will never work. You should understand what `switch` does in the first place.

It will execute the statements falling under the case which matches the switch argument.

In this case, `score` is an argument which is `95` but `score>=90` will always evaluate to either `true` or `false` and never matches an integer.

You should use `if` statements instead.

Also Java doesn't allow `booleans` in switch cases so yea.

Answer (score 0):

Simply **NO**

```
int score = 95;

switch(score)  {
   case (score >= 90):
      // do stuff
}
```

You are passing a `int` value to `switch`. So the case's must be in `int` values, where

```
(score >= 90)
```

Turns `boolean`.

Your case is a good candidaate for `if else`

Answer (score 0):

The [docs for switch-case](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statement state:

> a switch statement tests expressions based only on a single integer, enumerated value, or String object.

So there is no boolean. Doing so would make no sence since you only have two values: `true` or false.

What you could do is write a method which checks the score and then returns a one of the types `switch` can handle

For example:

```
enum CheckScore {
    SCORE_HIGHER_EQUAL_90,
    ...
}


public CheckScore checkScore(int score) {
    if(score >= 90) {
        return SCORE_HIGHER_EQUAL_90;
    } else if(...) {
        return ...
    }
}
```

and then use it in your switch:

```
switch(checkScore(score))  {
   case SCORE_HIGHER_EQUAL_90:
      // do stuff
}
```

... Or You could just use `if, else-if, else` directly!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, this is not possible as a language construct. But, just for fun, we could implement it by ourselves!

```
public class Switch<T, V> {

    public static interface Action<V> {
        V run();
    }

    private final T value;
    private boolean runAction = false;
    private boolean completed = false;
    private Action<V> actionToRun;

    public Switch(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    static public <T, V> Switch<T, V> on(T value) {
        return new Switch<T, V>(value);
    }

    public Switch<T, V> ifTrue(boolean condition) {
        runAction |= condition;
        return this;
    }

    public Switch<T, V> ifEquals(T other) {
        return ifTrue(value.equals(other));
    }

    public Switch<T, V> byDefault(Action<V> action) {
        this.actionToRun = action;
        return this;
    }

    public Switch<T, V> then(Action<V> action) {
        if (runAction && !completed) {
            actionToRun = action;
            completed = true;
        }
        return this;
    }

    public V getResult() {
        if (actionToRun == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("none of conditions matched and no default action was provided");
        }
        return actionToRun.run();
    }
}
```

`Switch` accepts any value to switch on and then provides functionality to match over boolean conditions (`ifTrue` method) or by exact matches (`ifEquals` method). Providing a value to switch on is needed just for the latter feature.

After building the conditions, user invokes `getResult` to obtain the result.

For example, we could create a method that tells us what it thinks about our score:

```
String tellMeMyScore(int score) {
    return Switch.<Integer, String> on(score).byDefault(new Action<String>() {
        public String run() {
            return "really poor score";
        }
    }).ifTrue(score > 95).then(new Action<String>() {
        public String run() {
            return "you rock!";
        }
    }).ifTrue(score > 65).then(new Action<String>() {
        public String run() {
            return "not bad, not bad";
        }
    }).ifEquals(42).then(new Action<String>() {
        public String run() {
            return "that's the answer!";
        }
    }).getResult();
}
```

This simple test:

```
for (int score : new int[] { 97, 85, 66, 55, 42, 32, 4 }) {
    System.out.println(score + ": " + tellMeMyScore(score));
}
```

Prints out:

```
97: you rock!
85: not bad, not bad
66: not bad, not bad
55: really poor score
42: that's the answer!
32: really poor score
4: really poor score
```

Answer (score 0):

If the relational operators are not working, then the only way to make them work is to erase the relational operators and enter the words manually.

for example:

```
System.out.println("Enter your grade: ");
int grade=kb.nextInt();

switch(grade) {
     case (80 | 81 | 82 | 83 | 84 | 85):
       System.out.println("LOW GRADES");
     case (86 | 87 | 88 | 89 | 90 | 91 | 92 | 93):
       System.out.println("AVERAGE GRADES");
    //so on, and so for until 100...
}
```